# SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table in dynamic query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm iterating through an array of table name strings and passing them to the following function:

```
FUNCTION table_empty(table_name VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
    row_count NUMBER := 0;
    empty_sql VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
    empty_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM :tab_name';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE empty_sql INTO row_count USING table_name;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Row Count: ' || table_name);

    RETURN row_count > 0;
END table_empty;
```

However, I get this error

> Unexpected error: ORA-00903: invalid table name

Does anybody have any idea what causes this?

Comment: Why `count(1)` and not the standard version? Just curious.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Honestly, I just never considered `COUNT(*)` as being standard. You're right though. An asterisk probably does make the statement more readable without having to understand what `COUNT` does with the parameter under the hood.

Comment: Fair enough :) From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/COUNT.html):  *If you specify the asterisk (\*), then this function returns all rows, including duplicates and nulls.* There used to be a myth that there were ways to make it faster by specifying a literal or the PK column, but it was never true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind variables are for *variables*, not identifiers. The table name (and other identifiers) need to be known when the dynamic statement is parsed; variable values are then applied when it is executed. At the moment when the statement is parsed the table name is interpreted literally as `:tab_name`, which is an invalid name.

You need to concatenate the name:

```
    empty_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ' || table_name;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE empty_sql INTO row_count;
```

You might want to validate the table name first though.

Answer (score 3):

This is the preferred solution (avoiding the concatenation of the table_name as string) using the **[SQL Macro](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/nfcon/sql-macros-282902288.html)** (requires Oracle 19.6 or higher)

In a SQL Macro you may pass safe a *table name as a parameter*.

*Define (table) SQL Macro*

```
create or replace  function my_count (t DBMS_TF.Table_t)
return  varchar2 SQL_MACRO
is
begin
return q'[
  select count(*) cnt from t]';
end;
/
```

*Usage for table `TAB`*

```
select cnt from my_count(tab);
```

More information and examples of SQL Macros can be found [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/21c/sql-macros-21c) and [there](https://marmite595538414.wordpress.com/blog/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this and it will alleviate the need of a wrapper to pass in the table. You can add a where clause for filtering.

This make some time to complete if you have tables with a large amount of rows

```
declare
tab_count number(3);
sql_stmt varchar2(100);
BEGIN
FOR cur_Rec IN (Select TABLE_NAME from user_tables) LOOP
  sql_stmt := 'SELECT count(*)  FROM '|| cur_Rec.TABLE_NAME;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt INTO tab_count ;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (cur_Rec.TABLE_NAME || ' ' || tab_count);
END LOOP;
END;
```